# What version of HornetQ does my JBoss uses?

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, hornetq

I am getting an exception when deploying one of my apps in a newer version of JBoss.

> NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hornetq.api.core.management.QueueControl.getMessageCount()I

My hypothesis is that the newer version of HornetQ in JBoss no longer offers that method. 
I would like to know how to find out what is the current hornetQ version in my JBoss so I can check the API docs for an alternative method.

Any idea/Suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigate to `modules\org\hornetq\main` in your JBoss AS installation directory.

In there you will find a number of jar files such as:

```
hornetq-core-<version>.jar
hornetq-jms-<version>.jar
```

Where version is the HornetQ version.

UPDATE:

```
ls -al /opt/jboss-7.1.x/modules/org/hornetq/main
drwxr-xr-x    1 www-data www-data     4096 Jul 11 17:39 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 www-data www-data        0 Jul 11 17:39 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 www-data www-data  1462224 Mar  9 23:14 hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--    1 www-data www-data     2545 Mar  9 23:14 hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar.index
-rw-r--r--    1 www-data www-data   229886 Mar  9 23:14 hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar
-rw-r--r--    1 www-data www-data      737 Mar  9 23:14 hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar.index
drwxr-xr-x    1 www-data www-data        0 Jul 11 17:39 lib
-rw-r--r--    1 www-data www-data       25 Mar  9 23:14 lib.index
-rw-r--r--    1 www-data www-data     1850 Mar  9 23:14 module.xml
```

Comment: Sorry i can't find it, can you provide sample full path?

Comment: I've updated my answer with results from my installation. The first part of the path i.e. /opt/jboss-7.1.x/ will be different for you.

Comment: just list the jar files in <jboss_main_path>/modules/org/hornetq/main

and you will find your hornetq version.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct path for hornetQ jar files
`jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/hornetq/main/`